# EventSubscriber endless redirect

Tags: 8, redirection, event-subscribers

I have Drupal 8.5.1 and I am trying to force a redirect for anonymous users to the [CAS](https://www.drupal.org/project/cas) login page. First I thought that the issue was related with the firing of the `checkAuthStatus` function below, however, the issue seems related to an **endless redirect**:

```
namespace Drupal\my_custom_module\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Event subscriber subscribing to KernelEvents::REQUEST.
 */
class RedirectAnonymousSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public function __construct() {
    $this->account = \Drupal::currentUser();
  }

  public function checkAuthStatus(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    \Drupal::logger('my_custom_module')->error('THIS IS A TEST');
    if ($this->account->isAnonymous()
        && \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() != 'cas.legacy_login'
        && \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() != 'cas.service') {
      $response = new RedirectResponse('/cas', 301);
      $response->send();
    }
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['checkAuthStatus', 27];
    return $events;
  }

}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: It should be fired on every page, are you sure the index page isn't just cached? Maybe try returning a [CacheableRedirectResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cache%21CacheableRedirectResponse.php/class/CacheableRedirectResponse/8.5.x) instead

Comment: The problem is, you should never send a response inside of a StackPHP application. Drupal continues to build its own response (the real frontpage) and stores this in the cache. Set the response in the event instead: `$event->setResponse($response);`

Comment: @Clive I have added `logger` calls and they are only executed when the visited URL is an internal page. On the front page is not being executed. So that means the `RedirectResponse` object is only created on internal pages, so using the `CacheableRedirectResponse` will not make any difference.

Comment: The front page is an internal page, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I have executed `drush cr` multiple times to clear the cache, but the issue continues.

Comment: Oh right I didn't notice you were actually sending the response yourself, what @4k4 said will definitely be the problem

Comment: @Clive When I visit the root URL (e.g. https://www.example.com) the code is not being executed. When I visit an internal URL (e.g. https://example.com/section) then it works. When I say "front page" I mean the root URL of the Drupal website (no ending slashes).

Comment: Understood, just for future reference and to avoid confusion if you come across it, when talking about paths _internal_ in Drupal is a term used to describe any page that is in the site (including the front page)

Comment: @4k4 That would make a good answer

Comment: @Clive Although I am sending the response, as I said before, the code is not being executed. I have added logger calls to check that the code was being executed, but the log only include calls that are from internal URL's. So changing the response will not make any difference, because the code is never executed on the root URL.

Comment: And as 4k4 said - **don't** send the response yourself. Set it in the `$event` instead, clear cache, and try again :) If it still doesn't work, update the question with the latest code you're using and I'm sure someone can help you get to the bottom of it

Comment: @Clive, I'm not sure if the priority is correct, for a good answer I would need to investigate this further.

Comment: Bless you for only adding carefully researched answers @4k4

Comment: @Clive I have updated my question with a more detailed description. I have added the `logger` call and a description text.

Comment: FWIW your code actually works for me on the front page of a stock D8/Commerce 2 install with all the usual contrib modules installed; I see the redirect happen, and the log message appears as expected after a cache clear. So there's definitely nothing stopping the event from firing on the home page. You have a redirect loop because you're not checking the URL, but other than that it's fine. `$event->setResponse($response);` should definitely be used instead of `$response->send()` though, to avoid potential issues

Comment: @Clive I have updated the code with `$event->setResponse($response);` and I have cleared the cache again. Now the redirect is working again. So it is solved! In any case, I do not understand why the Drupal Log did not print my `logger` calls when debugging. I thought the function itself was not being executed, as no log was being printed.

Comment: Now I have endless redirect, but this is a different problem. I have updated my question with the specific URL checking.

Comment: I'd forget the route and use `\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()` to be honest. I don't have time to write up an answer right now, please feel free to do so yourself to help future users or I'll try to get to it later. The reason that change fixed it, at a very high level, is because of caching. No time to explain in more detail, but again if I get time later I will do in an answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I have solved the issue thanks to the comments I received on my question. Here is the solution I found:

```
namespace Drupal\my_custom_module\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Event subscriber subscribing to KernelEvents::REQUEST.
 */
class RedirectAnonymousSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public function __construct() {
    $this->account = \Drupal::currentUser();
  }

  public function checkAuthStatus(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    if ($this->account->isAnonymous()
      && \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath() != '/cas'
      && \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath() != '/casservice') {
      $response = new RedirectResponse('/cas', 301);
      $event->setResponse($response);
    }
    return;
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['checkAuthStatus', 100];
    return $events;
  }

}
```

In short, the issue was related with the path checking and the `RedirectResponse` object management.

Comment: You needed an explicit `return()` at the end of the function?