# Endless redirect on paths containing question marks

Tags: 8, redirection

A similar question was posted here: [EventSubscriber endless redirect](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258778/eventsubscriber-endless-redirect)

But I haven't quite been able to implement a workable solution.

On Drupal 8.73: Basically we have a custom module that is redirecting to clean urls (so that /node/42 doesn't get indexed by google). I didn't write the module and I'm a little fuzzy on what it's doing and why. The module works fine except that urls with `?` in them endlessly redirect and get caught in a redirect loop. The browser eventually returns an error that the page is redirecting and will never load properly. Here is the module:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\MyModuleSubscriber.
 */

namespace Drupal\sjwc_tweaks\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;


/**
 * Event subscriptions for events dispatched by SimpleFbConnect.
 */
class TweaksSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public function onRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $baseUrl = $event->getRequest()->getBaseUrl();
    $attr = $event->getRequest()->attributes;
    if (null !== $attr && null !== $attr->get('node') && $attr->get('_controller') == '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeViewController::view') {
      $node = $attr->get('node');
      $nid = $node->id();
      $current_uri = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
      if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()) {
        $redirect_uri = '/';
      } else {
        $url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $nid]);
        $redirect_uri = $url->toString();
      }
      if ($redirect_uri != $current_uri) {
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($redirect_uri));
      }
    }
  }

  static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onRequest'];
    return $events;
  }

}
```

---

I believe this line is the issue:

```
$event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($redirect_uri));
```

At the issue linked above, a kind user suggested a solution that I do not quite understand, they said:

> The problem is, you should never send a response inside of a StackPHP
>   application. Drupal continues to build its own response (the real
>   frontpage) and stores this in the cache. Set the response in the event
>   instead: $event->setResponse($response);

I'm not sure exactly where he means by setting the response "in the event" instead.

Now, as this issue only is a problem on urls with `?` in them, I did find I could correct the issue by wrapping the line above, line 37 thusly:

```
if (strpos($current_uri, '?') != TRUE) {
  $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($redirect_uri));
}
```

However I worry this might cause unpredictable behavior and I prefer to fix this the right way the first time. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or overlooking or explain how I can "set the response in the event" instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent accessing a page with /node/37 directly when an alias has been set?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206562/how-do-i-prevent-accessing-a-page-with-node-37-directly-when-an-alias-has-been)

Comment: The comment you've quoted from the linked question is about this line `$response->send();` Your code is correct in this point. By the way, what you are trying to do is a route normalizer, which is planned to be included in core, see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2641118. In the meantime you can use the contrib module Redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manually add the query parameters to the redirect URL.

Add this code:

```
$query = [];
parse_str($current_uri, $query);
```

just below this code:

```
$current_uri = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
```

And then change this line:

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $nid]);
```

To this:

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $nid], ['query' => $query]);
```